# Excel VBA: Can't deselect ListBox items from listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a command button that processes selected items in a ListBox (ListBox4). While i CAN deselect all the items in that command's Click() procedure, I wanted to, if the user clicked in the ListBox, to THEN deselect everything in the ListBox, prior to their selecting again.

I have code like the following, but it never seems to get called:

```
Private Sub ListBox4_Click()
If Apply_Format_Occurred Then
For i = 0 To ListBox4.ListCount - 1
         ListBox4.Selected(i) = False
Next i
End Sub
```

Do i need an outside command, etc to do this? I was hoping to be able to do it like how i described.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

thanks,

Russ

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GotFocus event of the ListBox so the code runs when the ListBox receives focus from the user.
Here is an example showing coding for the button and the ListBox:

```
Dim Apply_Format_Occurred As Boolean

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '<other processes>
    Apply_Format_Occurred = True
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox4_Change()
    If Apply_Format_Occurred Then
        For i = 0 To ListBox4.ListCount - 1
             ListBox4.Selected(i) = False
        Next i
        Apply_Format_Occurred = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That didn't seem to make much difference. When i click in the ListBox, nothing is deselected. Any ideas?

Comment: If you copy-pasted the code you would have needed to change all references of ListBox1 to ListBox4- Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: It is written so it only deselects everything if the CommandButton was pressed before the ListBox receives focus. Did you want a different functionality?

Comment: That's the functionality i am wanting. There is a command that is called first, and i set the boolean value there, like in your CommandButton1_Click. I changed the code you sent so it DOES say ListBox4, rather than 1. In fact, when i set breakpoints for the code in the ListBox4_GotFocus(), it never gets to them.

Comment: That is very odd, the event should fire every time the ListBox regains system focus. Would it be possible for you to post the file somewhere so I can open it?

Comment: I can send you the excel file that contains the code and forms. I'll have to explain how it kind of works, and apologize for the code, i'm taking this over from someone else. If you want to tell me where i can post it?

Comment: You could use a web site like http://www.box.com to upload and share a link to the file.

Comment: If you like, my email address is russurquhart1@verizon.net. If you email me i can send the excel file to you with some instructions, and we can take this offline, if that would be more appropriate.

Comment: I thought you were referring to a ListBox embedded on a worksheet, the ListBox embedded in the UserForm does not fire a GotFocus event but using the Change event should work fine. I updated the code in the answer, try using the Change Event instead of GotFocus.

Comment: That did the trcik! Also, would this be the place where, once someone selected an item, i could return the attributes of the item they just selected? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, the Change event fires each time the selection within the ListBox changes.

Answer (score 0):

I see this thread is old and maybe there is an easy or more elegant way to un-select a list box item.  But, I figured out a way for my needs.  In my case I wanted the list box to un-select only if the same item was clicked.  If a new item was clicked, it would be selected as normal.  I had to use two static variable (a boolean and "old selection" placeholder).

There's probably a much easier way.  But, I'm new to it and and couldn't find it.  Hope this helps.  Setting selectedindex to -1 unselects everything. Altenatively and as effective is *listboxName*.ClearSelected()

```
    Private Sub lstPendingQuotes_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstPendingQuotes.Click

    Static blnSelectable As Boolean = True 'use static boolean to retain value between calls
    Static objOldSelected As Object = lstPendingQuotes.SelectedIndex 'use old selected in case a different index is selected

    'if nothing is already selected (as in first form open) allow the selection but change boolean to false and set the OldSelected variable to the current selection
    If blnSelectable Then
        blnSelectable = False
        objOldSelected = lstPendingQuotes.SelectedIndex
    ElseIf lstPendingQuotes.SelectedIndex = objOldSelected Then 'if an item is selected and the same item is clicked un-select all and reset boolean to true for a new possible selection
        lstPendingQuotes.SelectedIndex = -1 'can substitute lstPendingQuotes.ClearSelected()
        blnSelectable = True
    Else 'If a different index is chosen allow the new selection and change boolean to false so if the same item is clicked it will un-select
        objOldSelected = lstPendingQuotes.SelectedIndex
        blnSelectable = False
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an onclick event for my listbox. I tried listbox.listindex=-1 at the end of the code in that event. It wouldn't work.

I created a separate AfterUpdate event with the single line:
listbox.ListIndex = -1

works like a charm